# special characters in xml file with Python2.7

Tags: python, xml, string

I have several strings like this:

> "Programa Directrices de Gesti\xc3\xb3n Tur\xc3\xadstica"

That I should store in an xml file in this way

```
<content><![CDATA[Programa Directrices de Gestión Turística]]></content>
```

I use this code:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

data_cdata = doc.createCDATASection(text)
cdv = doc.createElement(tag)
cdv.appendChild(data_cdata)
root.appendChild(cdv)
doc.appendChild(root)
```

but the output is:

```
<content><![CDATA["Programa Directrices de Gesti\xc3\xb3n Tur\xc3\xadstica]]></content>
```

How i can do it?

(sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python does not represent characters outside of the ascii range like you would like. The special characters `\xc3\xb3` and `\xc3\xad` are related to hexadecimal ordinals of each character: `ó` and `í` .
It seems like your code does not translate the special characters very well. Instead of posting the actual `ó` and `í` it posts their respective representations: `\xc3\xb3` and `\xc3\xad`. Now I know nothing of the library you use, but I would search in the appendChild function for a quick fix regarding the translation. If you cannot find it, you could perhaps iterate over the `text` with a loop removing special characters and turning them into regular letters 
("ó" into "o").

I wish I could be of more help :).

Good luck,

Jesper